# Problems running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just installed the rails env using the Rails installer on my Mac OSX 10.7.4.

I create a project using the "rails new" command.

When I try to run the "rails server" command I get this message:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails_generator/options.rb:32:in `default_options': undefined method `write_inheritable_attribute' for Rails::Generator::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:90:in `<class:Base>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:85:in `<module:Generator>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:48:in `<module:Rails>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails_generator/base.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/rails_generator.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rails-2.3.14/bin/rails:15:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rails:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

When I run the $ ruby -v and $ gem -v, I get "ruby 1.9.3p194" and "1.8.24" respectively. What am I missing here? How can I get this server to run?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906472/why-do-i-get-error-undefined-method-write-inheritable-attribute-in-my-migrat), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849332/rails-is-broken-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-11-04), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078723/undefined-method-write-inheritable-attribute-for-railsgeneratorbaseclass). Solution in all 3 is to `gem install rails`.

Comment: Did you install rails using homebrew?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are trying to use a Rails 3.x command with Rails 2.3. Pre 3.0 you have to use the server script.

From within your application directory run:

```
./script/server
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Inherited a Rails 2.x project and was going crazy trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Install rails as a gem, `gem install rails` . As your are using rvm, the folder path displayed here shows rails 2.3.4, while you tried to run `rails server` . Check/change the rails version in your gem file and then do bundle install.